# Fix illegible macOS destructive alert button (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui, macos-big-sur, uiaccessibility

The default dark-mode macOS Big Sur `Alert.Button.destructive` is illegible with salmon-on-gray coloring failing WCAG contrast requirements with a 1.7 score.

The Text view passed into it does not accept styling. Anyone have an idea to fix this or should an app's alert system stick to AppKit?

[image]